# Unable to Knife Bootstrap Ubuntu Ec2 instance

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I am unable to Bootstrap an Ubuntu Node in My Chef workstation

I have set up Chef work station and chef server . I am able to upload the cookbooks to chef server . But I am unable to Bootstrap both windows and Ubuntu Nodes

Below is the code for the Bootstraping ,
1)Ubuntu :knife bootstrap  --ssh-user ubuntu -sudo -i

I am getting this error ,
 PTY requested: stderr will be merged into stdout
ERROR: Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /tmp/d20190613-2526-ckl14f/testnode.pem

---

2)Windows :

knife bootstrap windows winrm  -x Administrator -P random_Password

I am getting below error ,

ERROR: knife encountered an unexpected error
This may be a bug in the 'bootstrap windows winrm' knife command or plugin
Please collect the output of this command with the `-VVV` option before filing a bug report.
Exception: NameError: uninitialized constant Chef::Knife::Bootstrap::ChefVaultHandler

---

Answer (score 1):

This is a recently-introduced bug that has already been fixed, but has not yet been merged/released.  My understanding is that a release will happen somewhat soonish.  Until then, try to get a slightly older version of whatever tool (Workstation?) and see if that gets you around the issue.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a bug report, ticket, or issue?

Comment: @yoda Thank you very much . I used the previous version and  I was able resolve the issue . However ,Now i have encountered new problem which was not there before . I am unable to upload my cookbook .  The error i get is ERROR: Server returned error 500 for https://<server url>

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the 2nd issue, but after moving below three dependencies
1.require_relative "bootstrap/chef_vault_handler"
2. require_relative "bootstrap/client_builder"
3. require_relative "bootstrap/train_connector"
to the top of the file C:\opscode\chef-workstation\embedded\lib\ruby\gems\2.6.0\gems\chef-15.0.300-universal-mingw32\lib\chef\knife  it worked fine.

You can check the same on github link - https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/8461

Comment: I am using Ubuntu OS . I did however add the above three lines in chef-repo/.chef/knife.rb, But I got error saying  LoadError: cannot load such file -- /home/ubuntu/chef-repo/.chef/bootstrap/chef_vault_handler